# Unable to connect to Soap Server

Tags: soap

im trying to connect to the magento soap server.

I have set up the soap role and user that i want to use, and then i wrote a script called soap.php and placed it in my website public_html for testing, which looks like this:

```
<?php
// Magento login information
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$mage_url = 'https://mrandmrsgrey.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl';
$mage_user = 'soaper';
$mage_api_key = '24648625';
// Initialize the SOAP client
$soap = new SoapClient( $mage_url );
// Login to Magento
$session_id = $soap->login( $mage_user, $mage_api_key );
```

But for some reason when i run the script i get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find  in 'https://mrandmrsgrey.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl'

Ive crawled the net but any solutions that popped up havent worked i.e. turning off "Add Store Code to URLs"

Im running magento CE 1.7. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Please try with url "https://mrandmrsgrey.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl"      add index.php and try...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a SOAP web service, a `WSDL` file is the file that describes all the methods available in the service. This information is structured in such a way that the SoapClient will know the XML is needs to send to make the method calls.

The cryptic error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find in 'https://mrandmrsgrey.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl'

Is PHP telling you is had a problem with your the WSDL file.  If I load your WSDL file in a browser

```
https://mrandmrsgrey.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl
```

There's no XML WSDL available.

[image]

It appears someone has set your site to maintenance mode. Further, it appears that maintenance mode disables the API as well as the site.

Turn off maintenance mode (remove the `maintaince.flag` file in your document root) and you'll likely be able to access the API.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, even though i was logged in as admin and could see the front end of my website, the maintenance mode was still blocking wsdl entrance. Thanks Again!